# Remove background of an image in image view

Tags: swift, imageview

How can i edit the background of an image (not imageview) and set it to be transparent. I had search a lot but can find nothing. Any help?

Comment: Please add more information as to what you need help with. Perhaps some code of what you've already tried? You need to take a look at how to ask good questions

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Images don't have a background like imageViews. Are you using a "png" file with transparent background or just a "jpg" file?

Comment: Using a jpg file. But want to convert to a png file with transparent background.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you want to do image processing using swift?